# Volume section missing in material panel

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, volumetrics

I'm new to blender and trying to fiddle with materials. However, in the materials panel, the volume section is missing.

[image: screenshot]

I'm using Cycles. Is there something more to enable somewhere ?

Comment: Just click Use Nodes button. Cycles use different materials than Blender Render.

Comment: @Photon can't believe it was that simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using cycles you need to check the "use nodes" button in the screenshot above. once you have done that i suggest using the node editor to work with your materials instead of the properties panel shown in the image. if you need help using the node editor ask and i can help. i do not know much about volume shading in particular but i can help with nodes.